# Prove that: $x^x\cdot y^y \geq \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)^{x+y} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Prove that:

$$x^x \cdot y^y \geq \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)^{x+y} $$

for every $x, y > 0$

Where I got stuck:

$$x^x \cdot y^y \geq \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)^{x+y} \iff \ln(x^x \cdot y^y) \geq \ln \left[\left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)^{x+y} \right] $$

$$x\ln(x) + y\ln (y) \geq (x+y) \ln \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right) $$

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would try looking at the convexity of $f(x) = x \log x$ (which is convex because it has second derivative $f''(x) = \frac{1}{x} > 0$).

Comment: There is a mistake in your computation. $\ln(x^xy^y)=x\ln(x)+y\ln(y).$ (and then @DanielSchepler's suggestion finishes the proof).

Comment: Great, thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rewrite your inequality as $$\frac{x\ln(x)+y\ln(y)}2\geq \left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\ln\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$$

Now if $f(z)=z\ln z$, then $f'(z)=1+\ln z$ and $f’'(z)=\frac1z$ which is larger than $0$ for $z\in(0,\infty)$. Hence, $z\ln z$ is convex in the domain $(0,\infty)$.

As $x,y\in(0,\infty)$, we can conclude by Jensen's inequality that $$\frac{x\ln(x)+y\ln(y)}2\geq \left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\ln\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$$